# How to set Electron.js default page

Tags: javascript, electron

In my Electron app, links to a filename work:

i.e. `/folder1/index.html`

Links directly to the folder name do not work:

i.e. `/folder1`

Except for when there is a forward slash at the end:

i.e. `/folder1/`

When the user clicks on the link to a folder name they get a blank page with no ability to navigate.

`<a>` tags are being used for the links.

I have read the Electron documentation and searched Stack Overflow looking for a way to set a default page (i.e. index.html) so that the BrowserWindow will attempt to navigate to that when encountering a folder link. I was unable to find a way to do this. It wasn't exactly clear how to catch an error either.

My Electron app runs on Windows, since that is relevant

The electron version being used is 1.6.11

Comment: I would guess that this isn't possible, since the "default page" behaviour you're talking about is not a browser thing but instead a web server thing. You may be best off adjusting your links or running a web server locally in addition to your Electron application.

Comment: The web server is node.js (which electron wraps). So Electron should provide some kind of interface to modify this setting. It doesn't make sense to run two web servers in the same application.

Comment: Electron does not "wrap" a web server and thus does not have settings for a web server